# ニフティクラウド mobile backendの通信は暗号化されているのでしょうか

Tags: monaca

ニフティクラウド mobile backendで、monacaと連携したアプリ開発ができると聞きました。

ニフティクラウドのデータストア機能を使うと、monacaで作ったスマートフォンアプリとニフティクラウドのサーバーとの間で情報のやり取りができるようです。

この通信は、暗号化されているのでしょうか。

ご多忙のところ恐縮ですが、ご存じの方がいらっしゃったら、ご教示いただけないでしょうか。
暗号化されているかいないか、関連の仕様が記載されているウェブページがあれば、あわせてご教示いただけないでしょうか。

よろしくお願い申し上げます。

Answer (score 0):

はい、HTTPSで暗号化されています。データの暗号化も可能です。